# Ubuntu 14.04 Nvidia 331.38 Chrome renders with bugs

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, google-chrome

Ubuntu 14.04 x64
Chrome 35.0.1916.114
Using NVIDIA binary driver 331.38 (also tried X.Org X Server Nouveau)
Two monitors

Both in Unity and Gnome Chrome displays grey rectangles, on scroll it sometimes leaves some rectangular areas non-updated or doesn't remove old rectangles, but writes new text as if it was a new layer above the old texts. Firefox and Chromium didn't show this bug.

The screenshot:
[image: buggy chrome rendering]

Tried:
changing hardware acceleration in chrome,
using the Nvidia or x.org drivers
 - in all possible four combinations, including a cold reboot between the settings changes.

Ideas checked:
Turned off all extensions in Chrome. After this chrome started crashing upon startup.
Uninstalled google-chrome-stable using dpkg, deleted ~/.cache/google-chrome and ~/.config/google-chrome (only backed up SessionBuddy database)
Added google's repo to the repo list, installed from it.
With a fresh install still, there are render bugs.
So I enabled SessionBuddy and FlashControl extensions since there's no evidence they affect this behaviour.
Checked if there's ulimit - it says 'unlimited'.

The probability of rendering bugs increases with the number of tabs. Some tabs go completely grey and I can only refresh them or close.

Also, I've found chrome flags setting with lots of flags for render/gpu/hardware acceleration. Didn't try playing with them yet.

Probably there's some GPU memory limit per app/process? Or, maybe, other options?

**UPD:** The bug disappeared next day but emerged again today. Seems like the bug arises when I have more than 13 windows with more than 100 tabs total. Seems like it hits some memory/gpumem limits and the problem comes in play. When I close some tabs and join some windows the bug disappears after the F5 refresh. I closed and merged windows to 79 tabs and 7 windows total and the bug disappeared. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm I'm having the same problem. It's really not clear what's causing it, though.

Comment: @distilledchaos check the answer, people on google products forum have found the reason of the bug and the way to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it's ulimit -n that prevents Chrome from creating new shmem files.

### Temporary fix

(all the commands should be run within one terminal)

```
ulimit -Sn 4096
ulimit -Hn 4096
google-chrome
```

### Permanent fix

(requires reboot)

**Step one:**

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/security/limits.conf
```

add the lines (or check what lines to edit)

```
* soft nofile 8192
* hard nofile 65536
root soft nofile 8192
root hard nofile 65536
```

(seems like wildcard has no effect on root user, so the root user should be noted explicitly if needed)

**Step two:**

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/pam.d/common-session
```

add the line

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

**Step three:**

Reboot the machine

Comment: Both fixes do not fix the problem on my PC. Bug still seems to be unfixed, see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=136054

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug. See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=136054

Disabling GPU support seems to fix it for now:

```
google-chrome --disable-gpu
```